# Cypress.io - How to use Elements Collection

Tags: cypress

I should check if the page have 20 elements.

It’s very easy with Selenide

```
$$("[data-test='topic-item']").shouldHave(CollectionCondition.size(20));
```

But I haven’t idea how to do it with Cypress.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience at all with Selenide, but if I read your code correctly you are looking for the following. The element `[data-test='topic-item']` should exist 20 times, in that case you could test that with this code:

```js
cy.get('[data-test="topic-item"]')
  .should('have.length', 20)
```